# Integration error using R to evaluate overlapping distributions

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, integral

This question is a follow up to the original thread (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions)

I've modified the original code from the thread above to label the plots, but nothing much more.  I'm running into issues with the code working with one set of inputs, but not another.  As an R beginner, I'm just looking for help as to why.

```
mu1 <- 5
sd1 <- 1

mu2 <- 3
sd2 <- .75
```

This data set works.

[image: Working Probability of fit]

When I change the numbers, I hit an issue:

```
mu1 <- .3439
sd1 <- .0005

mu2 <- .3420
sd2 <- .00075
```

There's clearly an overlap, but the integral is not computing.

[image: Failed Probability of fit]

How is the integral failing when the numbers change? and how can I remedy? Do I not have enough x points in xs for the integral to compute?

Full Code below:

```
min.f1f2 <- function(x, mu1, mu2, sd1, sd2) {
  f1 <- dnorm(x, mean=mu1, sd=sd1)
  f2 <- dnorm(x, mean=mu2, sd=sd2)
  pmin(f1, f2)
}


mu1 <- .3439
sd1 <- .0005

mu2 <- .3420
sd2 <- .00075

xs <- seq(min(mu1 - 3*sd1, mu2 - 3*sd2), max(mu1 + 3*sd1, mu2 + 3*sd2), .00001)
f1 <- dnorm(xs, mean=mu1, sd=sd1)
f2 <- dnorm(xs, mean=mu2, sd=sd2)

plot(xs, f1, type="l", ylim=c(0, max(f1,f2)), ylab="density")
lines(xs, f2, lty="dotted")
ys <- min.f1f2(xs, mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2, sd1=sd1, sd2=sd2)
xs <- c(xs, xs[1])
ys <- c(ys, ys[1])
polygon(xs, ys, col="red")


### integrate to find % overlap
iP <- integrate(min.f1f2, -Inf, Inf, mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2, sd1=sd1, sd2=sd2)
VaLue <- iP$value
VaLue <- sprintf("%.1f %%", 100*VaLue)

#percentage on plot (in middle of overlap.. half of ys height )
text(((mu2 + 3*sd2)+(mu1 - 3*sd1))/2, max(ys)/2, VaLue)
#label f1
text(mu1+sd1,max(f1),"HOLE")
#label f2
text(mu2+sd2,max(f2),"PEG")
```

Comment: You lost me where you asserted a "hole" and a "pin" can have "normal distributions."  In theory that's impossible--neither can have negative radii--so evidently you're making some approximation.  Could you edit this question to be explicit about how you are parameterizing these geometric objects and how you are modeling those parameters with normal distributions?

Comment: Fair. The intent is to say the Inner Diameter of the hole has a mean and tolerance. The same goes for the Outer Diameter of the pin. So if my hole has a 0.3439±0.0015 tolerance, I assume the tolerance is based on 3 sigma and thus the standard deviation is 0.0005. I've updated my first example so that the hole or pin cannot become negative (good catch!).  Also added comments to show intent of pulling "acceptable" parts from inventory - Goal is to see chance any accepted parts not fitting based on the specifications alone.

Comment: It might help to recognize that this overlap integral has nothing to do with the question of whether the pin will be small enough to fit in the hole.  If you were to eliminate that diversion from your question, I suspect most readers would immediately recognize what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll clean up my question to match.

Comment: You seem to have thrown out all statistical elements of your question.  It now asks "why doesn't this code seem to work."  If that's really what you want to ask--knowing that it doesn't correctly answer the statistical question posed in the earlier version and in your comments--then please flag it for migration to SO.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your help on simplifying this.  I've flagged it for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for whatever reason integration fails for small numbers when approaching infinity  (or even much above or below the 3 sigma tails...).

I updated only the limits on the integral from -inf, inf to min(mu1 - 3*sd1, mu2 - 3*sd2), max(mu1 + 3*sd1, mu2 + 3*sd2) and I have an approximation again. Sure, it's not perfect, but I really only care about a handful of digits for my application.

Would really like to better understand why this failed in the first place when only the scale changed. Any ideas?

Updated code below.

```
min.f1f2 <- function(x, mu1, mu2, sd1, sd2) {
  f1 <- dnorm(x, mean=mu1, sd=sd1)
  f2 <- dnorm(x, mean=mu2, sd=sd2)
  pmin(f1, f2)
}

#HOLE 
mu1 <- .3439
sd1 <- .0005
#Peg
mu2 <- .3420
sd2 <- .00075

xs <- seq(min(mu1 - 3*sd1, mu2 - 3*sd2), max(mu1 + 3*sd1, mu2 + 3*sd2), .00001)
f1 <- dnorm(xs, mean=mu1, sd=sd1)
f2 <- dnorm(xs, mean=mu2, sd=sd2)

plot(xs, f1, type="l", ylim=c(0, max(f1,f2)), ylab="density")
lines(xs, f2, lty="dotted")
ys <- min.f1f2(xs, mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2, sd1=sd1, sd2=sd2)
xs <- c(xs, xs[1])
ys <- c(ys, ys[1])
polygon(xs, ys, col="red")


### integrate to find % overlap
iP <- integrate(min.f1f2, min(mu1 - 3*sd1, mu2 - 3*sd2), max(mu1 + 3*sd1, mu2 + 3*sd2), mu1=mu1, mu2=mu2, sd1=sd1, sd2=sd2)
VaLue <- iP$value
VaLue <- sprintf("%.1f %%", 100*VaLue)

#percentage on plot (in middle of overlap.. )
text(((mu2 + 3*sd2)+(mu1 - 3*sd1))/2, max(ys)/3.5, VaLue)
#label f1
text(mu1+sd1,max(f1),"HOLE")
#label f2
text(mu2+sd2,max(f2),"PEG")
```